# How to save file locally in flutter

Tags: flutter, save, offline

I have already implemented a share button in flutter which works completely offline. Like when we click the share button, it shares the file from the assets folder which I have already kept.
I want a similar offline implementation of the save button, like, when we click the save button, that particular file present in the assets folder should get saved in the smartphone of the user.